# Extracting MAC Address from arp table using grep regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep, arp

I am trying to extract MAC address from arp table without but it is returning a empty line.

I tried to use the command:

```
arp -a | grep eth1 | grep '^\A(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}):){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$\z'
```

The 'arp -a' command return:

```
? (192.168.36.20) at 80:e0:1d:43:b0:60 [ether] on eth1
? (192.168.0.1) at 34:4b:50:b7:ef:08 [ether] on usb0
? (172.17.140.200) at 10:c3:7b:c4:82:04 [ether] on eth0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved using:

```
arp -a | grep eth1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler way using `awk`:

```
$ arp | grep eth1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

See [GNU Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) manual for more.